# Failed to Load Command Puma: NameError: Wrong Constant Name 'Model-Names' Copy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production-environment

Just deployed to Heroku and successfullly migrated db. But site crashed with error saying there is 'NameError: Wrong Constant Name Companies Copy' where i have a Company model.

Using Rails 6.0.0.rc1
Ruby version 2.6.3

Checked through the entire code and confirmed that i did not initialize anything with the plural "Companies" name.

have checked through blogs and stackoverflow... there is no specific way to identify this issues.

```
2019-07-15T03:39:08.124899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -p 28862`
2019-07-15T03:39:10.206749+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2019-07-15T03:39:10.206793+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas                                                                                                              
2019-07-15T03:39:10.206795+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5                                                                                                                                            
2019-07-15T03:39:10.206797+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production                                                                                                                                                   
2019-07-15T03:39:14.734930+00:00 app[web.1]: ! Unable to load application: NameError: wrong constant name Companies copy
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735052+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma)                                                                                              
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735115+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: wrong constant name Companies copy                                                                                                                               
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735118+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:679:in `const_defined?'
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735120+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:679:in `cdef?'                                                                         
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735122+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:597:in `strict_autoload_path'                                                                      2019-07-15T03:39:14.735124+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:574:in `autoload_for?'                                                                             
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735126+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:488:in `autoload_subdir'                                                                           
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735128+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:477:in `block in set_autoloads_in_dir'                                                             
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735130+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:649:in `block in ls'                                                                               
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735132+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:646:in `foreach'                                                                                   
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735134+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:646:in `ls'                                                                                        
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735136+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:463:in `set_autoloads_in_dir'                                                                      
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735138+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:65:in `block in on_namespace_loaded'                                                     
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735139+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:64:in `each'                                                                             
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735141+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:64:in `on_namespace_loaded'                                                              
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735142+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:50:in `block in on_dir_autoloaded'                                                       
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735144+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:37:in `synchronize'                                                                      
2019-07-15T03:39:14.735145+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.8/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.
```

Hope anyone with similar experience can at least point me to where to look to solve or dissect this issue further.

Many thanks.

UPDATE:

Found a quick fix. The reason the error was raise was due to autoloading with with zeitwerk which is the default autoloader for rails 6.

I have not found the reason as to why I had the NameError. So, in the application.rb file, I reverted the autoloading back to the classic version which was used for rails before version 6. After that everything went well.

```
config.load_defaults "6.x"
config.autoloader = :classic
```

Comment: Try to find file with name `company copy.rb` (probably in `app/models`) and remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the input but have double checked and there is no file with that name though.. Even checked through the entire code base for lines containing word company or companies and found nothing illogical

Comment: I've investigated stack trace with sources of `zeitwerk` tag 2.1.8 and now I'm pretty sure you have either `company copy.rb` file OR `company copy` folder. Gem Source shows that the error was occurred while trying to "constantize" one of the file names. May be it is in your gems.

Comment: Hmmm.. even a global search for the word 'copy' or 'company copy' doesn't show anything. Perhaps is like what you said.... in the gems. After all i do have complex association between models with accept_nested_attributes that utilizes cocoon gem.. need to find time to dissect that.